# Search result page as a new page

Tags: search, multi-language

trying, reading but no luck.

So here is the story, my search result page dose not open as a page, but as domain.com/?s= I cant edit the search results... there is no page...

So If I could add some code that the search page would appear as domain.com/search that would solve my issue. I could edit the page and add the themes style? Now the domain.com/?s= style is different from the themes style...

Have already created the search page, but how to tell the search that it should open search results as search page (domain.com/search)?

in short from this 
domain.com/?s=
to this
domain.com/search

I hope it will work on multilangual site?
English - domain.com/search/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom template for search page:

```
<?php


 get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Comment: Thats not it. I want that my search results open in my own search page. A page that can be edited and so on...